# RxJava sewing two queries

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

How to sew two Observable in RxJava ?

`Observable<List<CalendarEvent>>`, for each CalendarEvent, I want to do network operation to read the (lat,lon) and fetch place name, and then combine place name back to CalendarEvent.

```
 public Observable<List<CalendarEvent>> getEvents() {
     // get events
     // translate each Event LatLng to Place and bind it to Event
     // return the events
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Observable<List<CalendarEvent>> getEvents() {
    List<CalendarEvent> sourceList = ...
    return Observable.from(sourceList) //emits each item separately
            .concatMap(calendarEvent -> applyPlaceName(calendarEvent)) //fetches places  and applies them for each item
            //fyi: concatMap executes requests sequentially, if you want do it in parallel - use flatMap instead
            .toList(); //collects items to list
}

//somewhere in your Networking class
public Observable<CalendarEvent> applyPlaceName(CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
    return Observable ... //do network call and apply placeName on item
}

//p.s. don't forget to apply appropriate Schedulers
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for something fancy here, this would roughly do what you want I think:

```
public class Foobar {

    void doSomethingWithEvents() {

        getEvents().subscribe(new Action1<List<CalendarEvent>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents) {

                for (CalendarEvent event : calendarEvents) {

                    getPlaceForEvent(event).subscribe(new Action1<Place>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Place place) {

                            event.setPlace(place);

                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        });
    }

    Observable<Place> getPlaceForEvent(CalendarEvent event) {
        return Observable.just(new Place());
    }


    Observable<List<CalendarEvent>> getEvents() {

        return Observable.just(new ArrayList<CalendarEvent>());

    }


}
```

Comment: thanks for looking, but, void doSomethingWithEvents()  should return **Observable<List<CalendarEvent>>**, as I am consuming this in presenter (MVP).